# Swift Combine Subscriptions, right flow and architectural choices

Tags: swift, combine

Let's say that:

• My application is a client of a Socket server.

• I'm free to write the Socket client implementation to fit with `Combine` as I prefer

I've implemented 2 solutions, one with `CurrentValueSubject` (quite easy) and a second with a custom subscription and a custom publisher that I'm not sure about. I really don't know which is the best way to bridge the code that I'm using to handle server messages with Combine.

Here is my code:

To simulate the socket server I've create a fake `SocketServerManager` that generates some events every `N` seconds:

```
protocol SocketServerManagerDelegate{
    func newEvent(event:String)
}

class SocketServerManager {

    let timing: Double
    var timerHandler:Timer? = nil
    var delegates:[SocketServerManagerDelegate] = []

    init(timing:Double){
        self.timing = timing
    }

    func start(){
        // Just start a timer that calls generateEvent to simulate some events
        timerHandler = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: timing, repeats: true){
            [weak self] _ in
            self?.generateEvent()
        }
        timerHandler?.fire()
    }


    private func generateEvent(){
        let events = ["New Player", "Player Disconnected", "Server Error"]
        let currentEvent = events.randomElement

        for delegate in delegates{
           delegate.newEvent(event: currentEvent)
        }
    }            
}
```

### Custom Publisher and Subscription

My custom subscription keeps  a reference to an instance of the server manager and to the subscriber. 
Also, it implements a `SocketServerManager` delegate. So that when the server has a new event it calls the subscription that can now send the `receive` event on the subscriber **(This is the choice where I have A LOT OF doubts...)**

```
class EventSubscription<S:Subscriber>:Subscription, SocketServerManagerDelegate 
    where S.Input == String{

    private var subscriber:S?
    private unowned var server:SocketServerManager

    init(sub:S, server:EventsServer){
        self.subscriber = sub
        self.server = server
    }

    func request(_ demand: Subscribers.Demand) {}

    func cancel() {
        subscriber = nil
    }

    // HERE IS WHERE I SEND THE EVENT TO THE SUBSCRIBER since this subscription 
    is a delegate of the server manager 
    func newEvent(event: Event) {
        _ = subscriber?.receive(event) 
    }
}
```

The publisher has nothing special...it will just create the subscription with the `receive` function. Also it appends the subscription to the list of delegates registered on the server so that the `generatesEvents` function can broadcast the event through the delegates (hence, through the subscriptions).

```
// PUBLISHER CODE ----------
func receive<S>(subscriber: S)
    where S:Subscriber,
    EventsPublisher.Failure == S.Failure,
    EventsPublisher.Output == S.Input {

        let subscription = EventSubscription(sub:subscriber, server: self.server)
        server.delegates.append(subscription)
        subscriber.receive(subscription: subscription)
}
```

What do you think about this implementation? to me it seems quite clunky, but I really don't know how to bridge the events from the Server Manager to Subscribers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it with the following simple & manageable approach (IMO this is not the right place for "delegate"s).

Completely testable module: consumer is SwiftUI view. Tested as worked with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2, however I don't see any platform limitations.

Demo:

[image: SockerServer emulate Combine demo]

Here is a scratchy idea code. Please find additional comments inline.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

protocol SocketServerManagerDelegate{
    func newEvent(event:String)
}

class SocketServerManager {

    // transparent subject that manages subscribers/subscriptions
    let publisher = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()

    let timing: Double
    var timerHandler:Timer? = nil

    init(timing:Double){
        self.timing = timing
    }

    func start(){
        // Just start a timer that calls generateEvent to simulate some events
        timerHandler = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: timing, repeats: true){
            [weak self] _ in
            self?.generateEvent()
        }
        timerHandler?.fire()
    }

    func stop(){
        publisher.send(completion: .finished) // notifies all that finished
    }

    private func generateEvent(){
        let events = ["New Player", "Player Disconnected", "Server Error"]
        guard let currentEvent = events.randomElement() else { return }

        publisher.send(currentEvent) // send to all subscribers
    }
}

// usage
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private let server = SocketServerManager(timing: 1)
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    func setup() {
        guard cancellables.isEmpty else { return } // already set up

        // add one example subscriber
        server.publisher
            .assign(to: \.value1, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)

        // add another example subscriber
        server.publisher
            .sink(receiveValue: { value in
                self.value2 = value
            })
            .store(in: &cancellables)

        server.start()
    }

    @Published var value1: String = "<unknown>"
    @Published var value2: String = "<unknown>"
}

// view demo
struct TestSocketServerPublisher: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Observer1: \(viewModel.value1)")
            Divider()
            Text("Observer2: \(viewModel.value2)")
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.viewModel.setup()
        }
    }
}

struct TestSocketServerPublisher_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestSocketServerPublisher()
    }
}
```